# Install pyyaml using pip/Add PyYaml as pip dependency

Tags: python, pip, yaml

I want to use PyYaml in my pip project, but am having trouble using it as a dependency. 
Mainly the problem is thet PyYaml in pip is not a cross platform install.

How do I install pyyaml using pip so that it works. Note, on a current fresh Ubuntu install I get the following error when running `pip install pyyaml`

```
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
  Running setup.py install for pyyaml
    checking if libyaml is compilable
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/check_libyaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/check_libyaml.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/check_libyaml.c:2:18: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.

    libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
    (if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
     specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
     modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)

Successfully installed pyyaml
```

Note that the error says "successfully installed" but it is not.
I can not `import yaml`

I am not looking for answers that say "use apt-get" due to my very first sentence. **I need the install to be cross platform and work as a pip dependency** I am not simply wondering on how to install it correctly.

If this is not possible, is there any library I can use in replacement?

Comment: Try to install in virtualenv, ``virtualenv pyenv && . pyenv/bin/activate && pip install pyyaml && python -c 'import yaml'`` is it working?

Comment: @spinus works with python3 but not python2.7

Comment: For me works also on python2.7. Pretty strange, I have no idea what's wrong. I know you wrote that it's fresh ubuntu, but is it really that fresh? No other ideas what can be wrong.

Comment: @spinus ok I am not sure. I just spawned a new instance in AWS to test it, and pyyaml is apparently a default library. Not sure why I didn't have it the first time. So the problem appears to be individualized. (might delete this question)

Comment: How did you install `pip`? It is not installed on a fresh Ubuntu install AFAIK

Answer (score 27):

You will need some extra packages to build it.

First of all you need to uninstall `pyyaml`, or it will complain later that it is already installed

```
pip uninstall pyyaml
```

Then install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev libpython2.7-dev
```

Finally install it again

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: libpython is default for python 2.7 on ubuntu

Comment: Nope, libyaml-dev is not required for pyyaml to work. If it's installed pyyaml can use it as more efficient implementation but it's not required. For me ``pip install pyyaml`` without external stuff and with the same error working just fine.

Comment: I need the install to work as a pip dependency and cross-platform. I am sorry if this wasnt clear, I have edited my question.

Comment: @Salem: This was great! Thanks!

[[before]] python -m timeit -s 'import yaml; y=open("config.yml", "r").read()' 'yaml.load(y) ==> 100 loops, best of 3: 5.63 msec per loop

[[after]] python -m timeit -s 'import yaml; y=open("config.yml", "r").read()' 'yaml.load(y, Loader=yaml.CLoader)' ==> 1000 loops, best of 3: 505 usec per loop

Comment: Note also that you might have to use `--no-cache-dir` when doing that last `pip install` to force `pip` to rerun the setup rather than using the cache.

Comment: Please explain how `apt-get` is cross-platform, as that is what the  OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Salem's answer as a guide, I was able to install PyYAML with libyaml bindings in Python 3.8 by doing the following:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev libpython3.8-dev
pip install pyyaml --global-option=--with-libyaml
```

Without specifying the `--global-option=--with-libyaml` option, it would not pick up the bindings, making the CSafeLoader and CSafeDumper classes inaccessible.

Answer (score -3):

*Virtual Environment Setting*

```
Python version: 3.6.3
Operating system: Windows, 64 Bits
```

Keras was not installing because of pyyaml setting not meeting up for python 3.6. 
I already had Anaconda installed in a different virtualenv with keras working fine (pyyaml module installed). I just used conda install pyyaml instead of pip and it got installed, thereby using `pip install keras` to install the keras library in my new virtual environment.

if you have anaconda installed already, try using

> conda install yaml

and see if it works. It worked for me!